# php echoing the ACTUAL statement of a query after its executed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This frustrates me a lot since i moved to PDO

I have something like this:

```
$sql = "select * FROM $table where id=:id";
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
$this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
bindValue(:id => $this->user_id);
$this->stmt->execute();
```

Now the select runs, doesnt break anything but i dont get expected results, if i echo $this->stmt i get something like this:

```
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => UPDATE `users` 
SET user_active= :user_active, user_activation_hash= :user_activation_hash
WHERE user_id = :user_id AND user_activation_hash = :verification_code )
```

Now that looks good so the problem is most likely with the values passed, so instead of passing a number i might have messed up quotes and passed $id as a string and it didnt evaluate the variable but i cannot figure a way out to see what the actual statement values were. There must be an easier way, it was very simple with standard mysql simply assign the query to a variable and echo it out or use or die mysql_error?

fwiw i tried  debugDumpParams and it only returns this:

```
UPDATE `users` SET user_active= :user_active, user_activation_hash= :user_activation_hash WHERE user_id = :user_id AND user_activation_hash = :verification_code Params: 4 Key: Name: [12] :user_active paramno=-1 name=[12] ":user_active" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [21] :user_activation_hash paramno=-1 name=[21] ":user_activation_hash" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [8] :user_id paramno=-1 name=[8] ":user_id" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [18] :verification_code paramno=-1 name=[18] ":verification_code" is_param=1 param_type=2
```

In guessing there is no debug dump values or something similar, its the values i want to debug

Comment: I think you mean `where id = :id` right?

Comment: Well, what *do* you get if not the expected result?

Comment: The first paragraph of code is dummy, the actual statement is quite large and includes a bunch of functions etc that are not relevant so i used an example but the PDOStatement object and debugDumpParams are real, as you can see they both match but they dont show the values of user_id or verification code. Im guessing thats where the problem is but it doesnt feel terribly efficient to try and guess whats wrong every time i come across an issue

Answer (score 0):

use `$stmt->debugDumpParams();`

Comment: It says Call to undefined method Database::debugDumpParams() when i use that?

Comment: ok got it working but it only returns paramaters which i can get with echoing $stmt already, see original post

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to print the final query that gets executed in DBMS, but I will point out the problems I noticed in your code.

The following statement is not using any parameterized placeholders i.e. `:id` or `?`:

```
$sql = "select * FROM $table where id=$id";
```

So, the following statement is kind of useless:

```
bindValue(:id => $this->user_id);
```

In the following statement, you're preparing `$query` variable, but you don't have `$query` defined.  It should be `$sql`.

```
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
```

Based on the above explanation, your code block should be:

```
$sql = "select * FROM $table where id=:id";
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

// Don't know the use of the following line so I'm commenting it out.
// $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);

$this->stmt->bindValue(:id => $this->user_id);
$this->stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Maybe `$id == ':id'`... but that would be a bit redundant.

Comment: Yeah the actual code itself wasnt important, its completely random and throw together so its really the concept of printing out the statement, i have working code with inserts and updates but its when they dont work the problem is. So for wasting your time on correcting those things, i should have pointed that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? You aren't fetching the result, `$stmt` is a PDOStatement object, you need to fetch the actual result set before you can work with it:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Will fetch all the results into an associative array.

Comment: At least you have a comforting upvote :) Err. not from me, to make it clear.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: :D That's true. I'm not sure if I'm the idiot, or everyone else are.

Comment: Pleading to your friends in the chat will always bring you one. It won't make your answer relevant though.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Probably, though I still don't get what's wrong with it. I'm not taking fetching for granted. If OP would edit his question   to include that he have indeed fetched, as well as what he got as opposed to what he expected, I'd gladly delete this answer.